# How to store user specific data after registration?

Tags: 7, hooks

Let us say you want to collect a bit more information about users during registration.
For example, instead of just username and email, I also want place of residenc. How do I collect and store this data per user?  At the end of the day I want to end up with place of residence of each user by doing an easy query.

**PS**: Currently, I have added extra fields to the form `user_register_form`, but I don't know how to associate this data with my new user because I don't have the new user id.

What is the right approach? Because I think this should be a trivial Drupal exercise, but am sweating `:)`.

I am using Drupal 7.1.

```
// implements hook_form_alter()
// user-register-form id the id in html but id that works in php is user_register_form
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'user_register_form':
      $form['placeofresidence']= array(
        '#title'=>'where do you stay?',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => true,
      );
      $form['#submit'][]='mycustommodule_submit'; //add to callback submit list
      break;
  }
} 

function mycustommodule_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $stayswhere=$form_state['values']['placeofresidence']; // how do I associate this with new user?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

users are a "fieldable entity" in Drupal 7. Just go to "configuration / people / account settings / manage fields" and add your fields. Make sure to check the "Display on user registration form" box.

For the "place of residence" I recommend the [addressfield](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) or [location](http://drupal.org/project/location) modules.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to approach this is use the 'data' field of user.  According to the documentation [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7), you could do something like this.  Let's say you have added a new form element to the new user registration form and want to save the data in it for something later after they authenticate themselves successfully for the first time.

```
function custom_module_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  //If the account is being created for the first time
  if (empty($account->original->login)) {
    $edit['data']['custom-field'] = $edit['custom-field'];
  }
}
```

This information will always be returned on a user_load and can be found in the $user->data array. For this example, it would be in $user->data['custom-field'].

Comment: Actually you dont even need to perform a user_load($uid). The data is always available through the global $user; object